# Trying to pray but my baby is sick

Tags: women

I have been trying to put my daughter to sleep so I can get up to pray but every time I go to leave her she wakes up and even when she is awake she is clingy and cries so I can't concentrate because her loudness increases and I feel she needs my comfort. I am alone all day and when my husband comes home he is tired and cannot sit with her. What do i do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well normally i would advise you to ask your husband to look after her once he is at home.

I think there are some ahadith (hadiths) which show that our Messenger (peace be upon him) used to pray even if his grandsons where playing around or him but i couldn't find an English translation, as it wasn't from one of the most [known sunna books](https://library.islamweb.net/hadith/display_hbook.php?hflag=1&bk_no=1306&pid=878421). Which i wanted to quote to show you that carrying a child won't break your prayer!

> عَنْ عبد الله بن مسعود ، قَالَ : كَانَ النَّبِيُّ صَلَّى اللَّهُ
>   عَلَيْهِ وَسَلَّمَ يُصَلِّي فَإِذَا سَجَدَ وَثَبَ الْحَسَنُ
>   وَالْحُسَيْنُ عَلَى ظَهْرِهِ ، فَإِذَا أَرَادُوا أَنْ يَمْنَعُوهُمَا
>   أَشَارَ إِلَيْهِمْ أَنْ دَعُوهُمَا ، فَلَمَّا صَلَّى وَضَعَهُمَا فِي
>   حِجْرِهِ ، ثُمَّ قَالَ : " مَنْ أَحَبَّنِي فَلْيُحِبَّ هَذَيْنِ

But at least i found a hadith which might be much better and clearer about this matter and help you:

> Narrated Abu Qatada Al-Ansari:
>
> Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) was praying and he was carrying Umama the
>   daughters of Zainab, the daughter of Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) and she was
>   the daughter of 'As bin Rabi'a bin `Abd Shams. When he prostrated, he
>   put her down and when he stood, he carried her (on his neck).
>
> [Sahih al-Bukhari. Al-Muwatta', Sunan abi Dawod]

So try to pray while carrying her and if your husband is home ask him whether he could help!

Comment: Thank you for your time! Also because of this predicament I have missed out on yesterday's prayers as well as today's as I had posted my question quite late received this response after the last prayer. Am I able to make up 2 days worth of prayer or is it not accepted, I apologise if these questions seem amateur but I have only been praying for a few months and don't know very much.

Comment: First scholars have some different point of views on how to: So what i found and use in my practice: If you have to make up more then 1 day (more then 5 fard prayers) you should pray at each time the actual prayer and the same prayers you need to catch up like: Actual maghrib with for example 2 other maghribs you missed the same when 'isha time comes pray actual 'isha first etc. . If it's less then a day you should pray the prayers you missed in order fajr then dhur then 'asr etc. then the actual!

Comment: Again thank you very much for your helpful answers, you have helped me immensely.

Comment: If you feel answered, make sure you don't forget to mark this 'Answered' by clicking the tick mark. @Hayat